# Oracle SQL - Select from multiple tables (Current and History)

Tags: sql, oracle

I currently have three tables with the same layouts. One is current (SY23), while the other two are from the past years (SY21 and SY22). Each table has thousands of rows and various attributes.

Sample Table layout:(SY21 means School Year 2020-2021 and so on...)

Table 1
STUDENTS_DEMOGRAPHICS_SY21

| DEMO_ID | SY_ID | SCH_ID | DIST_ID | ENROLLMENT | MALE | FEMALE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 654 | 323 | 331 |
| 2 | 1 | 2 | 2 | 1,980 | 998 | 982 |
| 3 | 1 | 3 | 1 | 4,903 | 2,980 | 1,923 |

Table 2
STUDENTS_DEMOGRAPHICS_SY22

| DEMO_ID | SY_ID | SCH_ID | DIST_ID | ENROLLMENT | MALE | FEMALE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 1 | 1 | 981 | 398 | 583 |
| 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2,246 | 983 | 1,263 |
| 3 | 2 | 3 | 1 | 5,186 | 2,084 | 3,102 |

Table 3
STUDENTS_DEMOGRAPHICS_SY23

| DEMO_ID | SY_ID | SCH_ID | DIST_ID | ENROLLMENT | MALE | FEMALE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 | 1 | 1 | 996 | 432 | 564 |
| 2 | 3 | 2 | 2 | 2,017 | 896 | 1,121 |
| 3 | 3 | 3 | 1 | 5,416 | 2,714 | 2,702 |

These are the other tables involved during the process:

SCHOOL_YEAR

| SY_ID | SCHOOL_YEAR |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2020-2021 |
| 2 | 2021-2022 |
| 3 | 2022-2023 |

SCHOOLS

| SCH_ID | SCHOOL_NAME |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | MY SCHOOL ELEMENTARY |
| 2 | YOUR SCHOOL MIDDLE |
| 3 | OUR SCHOOL HIGH |

SCH_DISTRICT

| DIST_ID | DISTRICT_NAME |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | District 1 |
| 2 | District 2 |

What is the appropriate process for joining these tables?  How do I retrieve the particular data such as school year 2020-2021 from these tables?  Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks so much.

Comment: It would be helpful if you google'd up some basic SQL tutorials and went through them first. Then folks here can help with areas where you get stuck.

Comment: Having a table per year seems inconvenient, but you could union those all together and then join the result of that to the other tables to apply filter conditions?

Comment: One option is to create a View , which will be a union of all the tables and you can select from the View.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I am so grateful for everyone's responses and thoughts. Take care.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not to be insulting, but this is about as basic as SQL gets. It'd be a good idea to invest a bit of time learning the language. There are many free resources.

However, since it can be helpful to see an example directly associated with your problem, this is an example the preferred join syntax. Here you get all the data for all years, and join to get the text descriptions of the lookups.

```
with consolidate_demographic_years as (
    select * 
      from STUDENTS_DEMOGRAPHICS_SY21
     union
    select * 
      from STUDENTS_DEMOGRAPHICS_SY22
     union
    select * 
      from STUDENTS_DEMOGRAPHICS_SY23
)
select school_lookup.school_name,
       district_lookup.district_name,
       year_lookup.school_year,
       cdy.*
  from consolidate_demographic_years cdy
 inner
  join schools school_lookup
    on cdy.sch_id = school_lookup.sch_id
 inner
  join school_year year_lookup
    on cdy.sy_id = year_lookup.sy_id
 inner
  join sch_district district_lookup
    on cdy.dist_id = district_lookup.dist_id
```

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to respond and offer suggestions. Take care.